# How to plot two random functions (Together)

Tags: plotting

I have  ploted the next following jump diffusion model using Mathematica 10

$$X_t=X_0 e^{\sigma W_t+(v-\sigma /2)t}(1+J_1)\cdots(1+J_{N_t})$$
namely, a Geometric Brownian motion with compound Poisson jumps.

For this I have used the next code:

```
Pp = 
  TransformedProcess[g[t] E^(j[t]), 
   {g \[Distributed] GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[v, σ, 1], 
    j \[Distributed] CompoundPoissonProcess[λ, NormalDistribution[0, 0.85]]}, 
   t];

data = RandomFunction[Pp /. {v -> 0.5, σ -> 0.5, λ -> 2.1, μ -> 0.92, δ -> 0.425, 
                             r -> 1}, {0, 3, 0.001}, 3];

ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

The thing is that, together with the resultant graphic, I would like to plot the generating Poisson Process. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: What does "plot the process" mean?

Comment: Plot the Poisson Stochastic Process, the function.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite following your question, but are you possibly looking for this?

```
Pp = TransformedProcess[{g[t] E^(j[t]), j[t]},
      {g \[Distributed] GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[v, \[Sigma], 1], 
       j \[Distributed] CompoundPoissonProcess[\[Lambda], NormalDistribution[0, 0.85]]}, t];

data = RandomFunction[Pp /.
                       {v -> 0.5, \[Sigma] -> 0.5, \[Lambda] -> 2.1,
                        \[Mu] -> 0.92, \[Delta] -> 0.425, r -> 1},
                      {0, 3, 0.001}];

ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**EDIT**:

"Improved" answer. This is really a hack: it splits the `TemporalData` object with two sets of data into two time-value arrays, and in addition to passing both arrays as-is to `ListLinePlot`, counts amount of value transitions before every point on the second of these time-value arrays. Not very pretty, but works.

```
Pp = TransformedProcess[{g[t] E^(j[t]), j[t]},
      {g \[Distributed] GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[v, \[Sigma], 1], 
       j \[Distributed] CompoundPoissonProcess[\[Lambda], NormalDistribution[0, 0.85]]}, t];

data = RandomFunction[Pp /.
                       {v -> 0.5, \[Sigma] -> 0.5, \[Lambda] -> 2.1,
                        \[Mu] -> 0.92, \[Delta] -> 0.425, r -> 1},
                      {0, 3, 0.001}];

processeddata = {#1, #2, {#2[[1]], #1} & @@@ 
      FoldList[{#1[[1]] + Boole[#1[[2, 2]] != #2[[2]]], #2} &, {0, 
        First@#2}, Rest@#2]} & @@ 
   Table[{#1, #2[[n]]} & @@@ First@data["Paths"], {n, 2}];

ListLinePlot[processeddata, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, @kirma. It is almost this. I want to plot a function that for each jump increments one unit when the jumps in the grafic ocurr. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PoissonProcess.html

Comment: @Edin_91 Improved the answer; sadly I don't know how to do this natively on the side of random processes.

Comment: Yes, that it is exactly what I need. Could you provide me the code to plot the Poisson Process and Compund Process together with the Geometric Brownian Motion? (I mean to combine your both answer)

Comment: If you give me points in my question will be able to point you up :)

Comment: If you need any explanation don´t  hesitate to ask me

Comment: @Edin_91 I think now it is what you wanted.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot :) When I get to 15 of reputation I will give you all the marks :)